# "@click=methodName(id)" function is not returning the id in vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I have following code,

**Laravel view blade template**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
         <div class="col-md-8">
            <div id='app'>
             <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @click="openModal()">Add Order</button>
             <modal v-if='showModal' @close='showModal = false'></modal>
                 <ul class='list-group'>
                      <li 
                  class='list-group-item' 
                  v-for="order in orders.data.data" 
                  :key="order.id">
                  <strong>@{{ order.status }}</strong>&nbsp;|&nbsp;
                  @{{ order.customer_name }}&nbsp;|&nbsp;
                  @{{ order.shipping_method }} &nbsp;|&nbsp;
                  @{{ order.products }} 

                       <button 
                    @click='openModal(order.id)' 
                    class='btn btn-primary btn-xs float-right mx-1'>
                    Edit
                  </button> &nbsp; 
                  <button 
                    @click='deleteOrder(order.id)' 
                    class='btn btn-danger btn-xs float-right mx-1'>
                      Delete
                   </button> 
                </li> 
              </ul> 
              <pagination :data="orders.data" @pagination-change-page="fetchOrders"></pagination> 
            </div> 
        </div> 
      </div> 
  </div> 
 </div> 

 @endsection
```

**app.js file**

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

Vue.use(require('vue-resource'));

Vue.component('pagination', require('laravel-vue-pagination'));
Vue.component('modal', require('./components/Modal.vue').default);

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data(){
      return{
        showModal:false,
        modalType:'',
        orders:{},
        pagination:{
          'current_page':1
        }
      }
    },
    methods:{
      openModal(id){
        if(id == null){
          this.modalType = 'Add';
        }else{
          this.modalType = 'Edit';
        }
        console.log(this.modalType);
        this.showModal=true;
     },
     closeModal(){
        this.showModal=false;
     },
     fetchOrders(page=1){
        axios.get('api/orders?page='+page)
          .then(response =>{
            this.orders = response;
          })
      .catch(error =>{
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
},
mounted(){
  this.fetchOrders();
}
});
```

Here i expect *openModal(id)* method's `console.log(this.modalType)` to execute because immediately below line `this.showModal=true` gets executed.

But my expectation don't work. console.log line don't get executed.

What has gone wrong in my code ?

You can see the code live at this link [Here](http://hidden-eyrie-83641.herokuapp.com/)

Hope this proves that this is a functioning bug or some spooky thing happening behind the scenes.

Comment: Hi , Thanks for quick reply. i edited the original post and added a link to live server. There you can inspect the issue.

Comment: thats how it is on your page: 52205++ : `openModal: function openModal() {
      this.showModal = true;
    },
    closeModal: function closeModal() {
      this.showModal = false;
    },` so nothing spookie ;)

Comment: Everything is working as expected in the app that you have linked, except that there is no `console.log` to check